# Why linux kernel TCPIP stack do not use some design pattern to process skb like Chain Of Responsibility?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp

Now I'm reading ipv6 code in linux kernel. I found there are lots of functions, which one call another, to process skb. Code like this:

```
Func1(skb) {  Func2(skb) }
Func2(skb) {  Func3(skb) }
Func3(skb) {  Func4(skb) }
...
```

So the problem is, there will be a ***DEEP CALL TRACE*** in this process, such as:

```
Func4
Func3
Func2
Func1
```

So why not code like this:

```
Func(skb) { Subfunc1(skb); Subfunc2(skb); Subfunc3(skb); ...}
```

And the CALL TRACE is, just 2 layer.

```
SubfuncX
Func
```

If CALL TRACE is too deep, I think, 1) is difficult to debug, 2) may be some problem when use VETH pair device.

So if that's true, what's the reason to design like this?

This is ipv6 function calls:

[image]

Comment: The reasons to make small functions might be (but not cover all cases): **a)** re-usability of some parts in the other functions; **b)** splitting big function for smaller blocks to make it maintainable (often b/c of deindentation of code blocks); **c)** split out small function as a so called *helper* to make error handling less twisted.

Comment: @0andriy, and probably function inlining will eliminate the stack frames and the levels the asker is seeing.  Linux kernel is largely dependant on gcc and its code optimisations.